# Как использовать в PyEnchant словари, не загружая их в саму библиотеку, а загрузив их в пользовательские файлы?

Tags: python

Использую библиотеку PyEnchant для проверки орфографии на страницах сайта. Всё хорошо, кроме того, что словари hunspell(backend PyEnchant) необходимо загружать в саму библиотеку. Так и не смог найти способ, как заставить его загружать словари из нужной мне папки. В документации только указано определение кастомных словарей. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ?

Comment: `pwl = enchant.request_pwl_dict("mywords.txt")`  или  `d2 = enchant.DictWithPWL("en_US","mywords.txt")`  - вот же в документации написано. Просто укажите вместо кастомного словаря путь к вашему словарю и используйте как Personal Word Lists

Comment: хм, почему то был уверен, что персональные и основные словари имеют разные интерфейсы. Спасибо, что указали на такое простое, но незамеченное решение

Comment: Пожалуйста ) Документация почти всегда такая штука, которую скучновато читать )

Comment: Хотя нет, к сожалению, этот способ не работает. Действительно, основные словари и пользовательские различаются. Этот способ создаёт пользовательский файл без расширения, вместо загрузки двух словарей ru_RU.dic и ru_RU.aff в один. Теоретически,я  могу загрузить dic и использовать его, но это будет отличаться от того, что хотелось бы изначально

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/faq.html#how-can-i-use-a-custom-location-for-storing-enchant-dictionaries)

Comment: да, несколько часов здесь провёл, а затем с каждой функцией игрался. К сожалению, они загружают только кастомные словари. Если нет кастомного словаря с названием, как запрошено, то просто создают свой.

Comment: У вас словари для hunspell? Проверьте, что используете нужный провайдер. Создаете переменную окружения ENCHANT_CONFIG_DIR = "путь_к_папке_со_словарями", дальше библиотека должна подхватить словари из этой папки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вроде вашу проблему. В папке со словарями создаете папку `hunspell` и копируете/перемещаете туда ваши словари. Создаете локальную переменную `ENCHANT_CONFIG_DIR` и присваиваете ей значение `путь\к\папке\со\словарями` без указания вложенной папки `hunspell`.

***Windows:***

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('ENCHANT_CONFIG_DIR','путь\к\папке\со\словарями',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

***Linux:***

```
export ENCHANT_CONFIG_DIR='/папка/со/словарями'
```

После этого все должно заработать (у меня, по крайней мере, заработало). Удачи!

**UPDATE**

А если используете виртуальное окружение, то внесите переменную в файл `.env`